# Samba public share - access denied

Tags: samba, fedora

I'm trying to configure Samba for sharing public folders - without necessity to log in. I'm using Fedora 16.

```
$ smbd --version
Version 3.6.1-74.fc16
```

Config:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   security = share
   hosts allow =  192.168.
   load printers = yes
   guest account = nobody
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 50
   domain master = no
   local master = yes
   os level = 35
   null passwords = true
   username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
   name resolve order = hosts wins bcast
   dns proxy = no

[test]
   comment = Pliki Estomedu
   path = /tmp/test/share
   public = yes
   writable = yes
   browseable = yes
   force user = nobody
   force group = nogroup
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
   available = yes
```

Path:

```
ls -la /tmp/test/share/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 13:09 .
drwxrwxrwx. 3 root root 4096 Nov 14 13:09 ..
```

smbusers:

```
# Unix_name = SMB_name1 SMB_name2 ...
root = admin
nobody = guest pcguest smbguest
```

What I get when I try to connect (providing empty password):

```
$ smbclient \\\\localhost\\test
WARNING: The security=share option is deprecated
Enter root's password:
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.1-74.fc16]
Server not using user level security and no password supplied.
smb: \> ls
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \*
```

Please help. The share is visible from WinXP and Win7 but get access denied message as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an alert:

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/smbd from read access on the directory share.
```

The best solution is to allow sharing only chosen directories:

```
/usr/sbin/semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t <path>
```

You can also allow SAMBA to share all directories:

```
setsebool -P samba_export_all_ro 1
```

Comment: A better solution would be to use /usr/sbin/semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t <path> and just add that directory instead of allowing all directories to be shared with samba. See more at http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext.html

Comment: Your are right. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: You can also use `setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs 1` for home directories.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with you, I saw that in smb.conf. It solved my problem

Security-Enhanced Linux (SELinux) Notes:

```
#
# Turn the samba_domain_controller Boolean on to allow Samba to use the useradd
# and groupadd family of binaries. Run the following command as the root user to
# turn this Boolean on:
# setsebool -P samba_domain_controller on
#
# Turn the samba_enable_home_dirs Boolean on if you want to share home
# directories via Samba. Run the following command as the root user to turn this
# Boolean on:
# setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs on
#
# If you create a new directory, such as a new top-level directory, label it
# with samba_share_t so that SELinux allows Samba to read and write to it. Do
# not label system directories, such as /etc/ and /home/, with samba_share_t, as
# such directories should already have an SELinux label.
#
# Run the "ls -ldZ /path/to/directory" command to view the current SELinux
# label for a given directory.
#
# Set SELinux labels only on files and directories you have created. Use the
# chcon command to temporarily change a label:
# chcon -t samba_share_t /path/to/directory
#
# Changes made via chcon are lost when the file system is relabeled or commands
# such as restorecon are run.
#
# Use the samba_export_all_ro or samba_export_all_rw Boolean to share system
# directories. To share such directories and only allow read-only permissions:
# setsebool -P samba_export_all_ro on
# To share such directories and allow read and write permissions:
# setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw on
#
# To run scripts (preexec/root prexec/print command/...), copy them to the
# /var/lib/samba/scripts/ directory so that SELinux will allow smbd to run them.
# Note that if you move the scripts to /var/lib/samba/scripts/, they retain
# their existing SELinux labels, which may be labels that SELinux does not allow
# smbd to run. Copying the scripts will result in the correct SELinux labels.
# Run the "restorecon -R -v /var/lib/samba/scripts" command as the root user to
# apply the correct SELinux labels to these files.
```